# Tipo de Dato Money SqlServer a Java

Tags: java

Tengo un jtable la cual tengo registros cargados de una base de datos SqlServer, tengo problemas con descarga la informacion a Excel, las columnas de tipo Money no me descarga.

Comparto parte del codigo donde tengo el problema, cual seria el instanceof para este tipo de datos? ya probe con varios tipo de datos sin exito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando tengas dudas sobre cual tipo de datos es un objeto, puedes utilizar el método `.getClass()` que tiene todo objeto en Java, te muestro un ejemplo de aplicación:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class ClaseObjeto {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Object value = new BigDecimal("20.35");

        System.out.println(value.getClass());
    }
}
```

En este caso instanciamos una clase `BigDecimal` y la cagamos a un `Object`, como en tu caso asumiremos que no sabemos que tipo es el objeto y para saberlo utilizamos `value.getClass()` lo cual nos retornara `class java.math.BigDecimal` con esto ya puedes agregar la validación `instanceof` según el valor que obtengas.